# QGIS delimited text file UTF-16 missing values

Tags: excel, qgis

I have a CSV file of species observations that has two separate columns for latitude and longitude stored in decimal degrees. Some of the other attribute fields' cells appear blank but when I open the CSV file in QGIS as a text delimited file, the blank cells are collapsed and treated as missing values. However, when I save the file as a UTF-16 text file format, the blanks are treated as null values, which is what I want. Why is this the case? Thank you!